# Конфликт между двумя библиотеками гугла

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api

Разрабатываю приложение где есть и гугл карты и гугл пай в итоге.
Одна из этих библиотекам перезаписывает друг друга, как понял у них общее `new google`.

Может кто подсказать как такое можно обойти?

Comment: А что за конфликт происходит?

Comment: Ну я в верху страницы загружаю google pay
внизу google map
в итоге у них одинаковое название объекта google
и google map перезаписывает google pay.

Comment: А конфликт в чем выражается? Что-то не работает? Ошибки происходят?

Comment: Ну я на вкладке гугл мап потом я перехожу на вкладку оплаты и ожидаю получить такой объект new google.payments но в объекте google есть только google.map

Comment: Понятно, что ничего не понятно) Пожалуйста, приведите код, который бы воспроизводил проблему. По идеи, они должны уметь работать вместе. Также, покажите, как вы их подключаете.

Comment: Так, только сейчас понял, что вопрос я задал вообще не корректно.
Я делал сайт используя vue2-google-map и загружал google pay до этого...
Я сейчас еще раз проверил как я их загружаю, сверился с документацией и все заработало. 
Спасибо вам, я понял что не правильно загружал эти библиотеки.
Можете сказать как закрыть вопрос?

Comment: Там снизу вопроса есть кнопка "Закрыть". Но вы вместо закрытия, лучше приведите ответ, как правильно подключить библиотеки. Возможно, это поможет кому-то в будущем.